# How to turn off service when system shut down?

Tags: android, service, shutdown

I've got some methods in `onDestroy` in my service. They must be called to set some application settings. Maybe there is a possibility to receive some kind of broadcast to set the settings values? As I understand, this service won't be active after the system reboots. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I've got some methods in onDestroy in my service

`onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called on a service. For example, if the user force-stops you from Settings, or you crash with an exception, or Android needs RAM in a hurry and terminates your process, `onDestroy()` is not called.

> They must be called to set some application settings.

Then you should be calling them sometime other than `onDestroy()`.

> Maby there is a possibility to recive some kind of broadcast and even set the settings values?

You can try having your service listen for the `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` broadcast, but that will not solve your problem, as there are other scenarios in which `onDestroy()` will not be called, as noted above.

> As I anderstand, this service when the system reboot won't be active

Correct.

Comment: I ran into an issue because onDestroy was not getting called during shut down. CommonsWare, in the official documentation it does say that onDestroy() is the place to put shutdown code, and does not have a warning saying that there's no guarantee. However, you do seem to be correct -- is there an official documentation somewhere about that?

Comment: @Kevin: Take a look at the docs on `Activity`, particularly the lifecycle diagram.

Comment: I figured out why it works like that. In the system there is no need to call onDestroy, because application should be prepared on unexpected shutdown, ie. someone remove the baterry. The best approach is to set those program settings while activity starts. At first I've got some problems in setting them in the beggining but after a while of hard thinking i made it. Now I'm sure, that when something wrong occurs, after reebot my application will work correct.